# Decode Javascript FileReader Base64 in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, base64, decode

I have the following Javascript-Code for Converting a file into base64:

```
File.prototype.convertToBase64 = function (callback) {
    var FR = new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function (e) {
        callback(e.target.result)
    };
    FR.readAsDataURL(this);
}
```

an example output would be:

`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj [...] /j+vigYmLtYx9n0tGzJIyZKIzsYyRRWj0RfdWtCiQdF9rH8f18SMciL7X8DJMySJ8uC4JDRWjH8CEiitULVaMf68GQYn2PvskyciSs26tDWr0ooorsWi0WiFIei0Y/10QkQkWWXo+xaNjetdjHo9YlFdi1eiell6LRj/AGIshIUjcKRej1Ws`

But I can't decode it with this:
`byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image);`

It says that it can't recognize the layout of the data. How can I decode the base64 data coming from FileReader in JS in C#?

Comment: just a wild guess, but I think that the decoder doesn't like the header of the data-uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,`

Comment: @Thomas thats it. I will add it as an answer.

Comment: You are basically stilling his answer by answering your own question and marking that as the right answer when @Thomas deserves the credit.

Comment: Why don't you just upload the file as binary? base64 cost more

Comment: @Endless is there a mark on my answer? Is there an answer by Thomas? Haven't I credited Thomas in my answer?

Comment: @Endless I am using SignalR as Transport between Layout and Backend. Uploading as binary is a little bit more complicated as base64. And for JS the client is converting the image into base64. The process of the site is stopped while the converting is in progress. So it isn't that costly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas I found a solution.

The C#-Decoder doesn't like the header: `data:image/jpeg;base64,`

You can fix it with this short code:

```
int index = base64Image.IndexOf("base64,") + "base64,".Length;
string base64String = base64Image.Remove(0, index);
```